# Grand Central Dispatch: What happens when queues get overloaded?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Pretty simple question that I haven't found anywhere in documentation or tutorials on GCD: What happens if I'm submitting work to queues faster than it's being processed and removed? I'm aware that GCD queues have no size limit, would work just pile up until the program runs out of memory? Is there any way to properly handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens if I'm submitting work to queues faster than it's being processed and removed?

It depends.

- If dispatching tasks to a single/shared serial queue, they will just be added to the queue and it will process them in a FIFO manner. No problem. Memory is your only constraint.
- If dispatching tasks to a concurrent queue, though, you end up with “thread explosion”, and you will quickly exhaust the limited number of worker threads available for that quality-of-service (QoS). This can result in unpredictable behaviors should the OS need to avail itself of a queue of the same QoS. Thus, you must be very careful to avoid this thread explosion.

  See a discussion on thread explosion WWDC 2015 [Building Responsive and Efficient Apps with GCD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/718/?time=1952) and again in WWDC 2016 [Concurrent Programming With GCD in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=454).

> Is there any way to properly handle this situation?

It is hard to answer that in the abstract. Different situations call for different solutions.

In the case of thread explosion, the solution is to constrain the degree of concurrency using `concurrentPerform` (limiting the concurrency to the number of cores on your device). Or we use operation queues and their `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to limit the degree of concurrency to something reasonable. There are other patterns, too, but the idea is to constrain concurrency to something suitable for the device in question.

But if you're just dispatching a large number of tasks to a serial queue, there's not much you can do (other than looking for parallelism opportunities, to make efficient use of all of CPU’s cores). But that's OK, as that is the whole purpose of a queue, to let it perform tasks in the order they were submitted, even if the queue can't keep up. It wouldn’t be a “queue” if it didn’t follow this FIFO sort of pattern.

Now if dealing with real-time data that cannot be processed quickly enough, you have a different problem. In that case, you might want to decouple the capture of the input from the processing and decide how to you want to handle it. E.g. if you can't keep up with real-time processing of a video, for example, you have a choice. Either you start dropping frames or process the data asynchronously/later. You just have to decide what is right for your use case. We cannot answer this question in the abstract.

Comment: How is limiting concurrent work with your methods different from the semaphore method proposed [here](https://www.swiftpal.io/articles/how-to-avoid-thread-explosion-and-deadlock-with-gcd-in-swift)?

Comment: I’ve [written about that semaphore technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57831146/1271826) and that was explicitly what I was thinking about when, above, I wrote “There are other patterns, too.” It’s just a less intuitive pattern (many newer developers don’t immediately understand why you’re waiting _before_ signaling, why you’re using non-zero value, etc.). It’s also more fragile approach (e.g. a simple path of execution where you forget to `signal` and you deadlock). Also, `concurrentPerform` is dynamically optimized for your number of cores, for maximum efficiency. But semaphores work.